# Determine the unknown relationship between bytes input and value displayed

Tags: c++, type-conversion

there are two programs, which are connected through shared memory. In Program A, a c++ console application there are 4 bytes reserved for a value, which will be visualized in program B. I have no idea what relation is between the written byte value and the shown value?!

Note: all values are decimal notation;

If program A sets the 4 bytes to 0, 0, 0, 0, program B will show 0;

If program A sets the 4 bytes to 1, 1, 1, 1, program B will show 0;

... remains until the value jumps to 57, maybe the reason is that the shared memory is not updated that fast. I am more interested to detect the following relation:

If program A sets the 4 bytes to 57, 57, 57, 57, program B will show 0.176643;

If program A sets the 4 bytes to 58, 58, 58, 58, program B will show 0.710401;

If program A sets the 4 bytes to 59, 59, 59, 59, program B will show 2.856924;

If program A sets the 4 bytes to 60, 60, 60, 60, program B will show 11.488970;

If program A sets the 4 bytes to 61, 61, 61, 61, program B will show 46.200980;

Of course I need to get the relation because I want to set the shown value to a specific number.

Comment: @MitchWheat the question makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program B appears to be treating the four bytes as an IEEE-754 single precision `float`, and then multiplying that number by 1000.0.

If you put the hexadecimal equivalent of your input values in this [hex to float conversion tool](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/32bit.html) you will see that the decimal digits correspond to the values you have shown:

```
57 = 0x39, 0x39393939 -> 1.7664292e-4
58 = 0x3a, 0x3a3a3a3a -> 7.1040133e-4
59 = 0x3b, 0x3b3b3b3b -> 2.8569240e-3
60 = 0x3c, 0x3c3c3c3c -> 1.1488970e-2
61 = 0x3d, 0x3d3d3d3d -> 4.6200980e-2
```

It's as if you had written, e.g.:

```
uint8_t a[4] = { 57, 57, 57, 57 };
float *fp = static_cast<float *>a;
float f = (*fp) * 1000.0;
```

Comment: and what does that have to do with a "shared memory environment"??

Comment: @MitchWheat the OP described a problem where opaque data sent from A (over shared memory) was being displayed a different format at B.  You could argue that the shared memory is a red herring, since it could equally have been say, an IP socket or any other IPC mechanism.  In any event, the solution was trivially found.